# Burgers' equation - Integrate discontinuity over rectangle

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, entropy, hyperbolic-equations

I am studying conservation laws and hyperbolic systems, particularly, Burgers' equation and shocks, and have a doubt at page 40 of the [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=3WhqLPcMdPsC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false) *Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws* by R.J. LeVeque (Birkäuser, 1992).

I could not understand the following calculation:

> If a discontinuity is present, then integrating $(u^2)_t + (\frac{2}{3}u^3)_x$ over an infinitesimal rectangle as in Figure 3.12 gives
>   $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}u^2(x,t)\, dx \bigg|^{t_2}_{t_1} + \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\dfrac{2}{3}u^3(x,t)\, dt \bigg|^{x_2}_{x_1} = s_1\Delta t(u_l^2-u_r^2)+\dfrac{2}{3}\Delta t (u_r^3-u_l^3)+O(\Delta t^2)$$

where

> [image: crobar]

We took an infinitesimal rectangle over a shock and have $s_1=\tfrac{1}{2}(u_l+u_r)$. Here, $u_l$ is the solution of $u(x,0)$ at left of $x=0$ and $u_r$ is the value at right (Riemann problem).

$O(\Delta t^2)$ means some quantity depending of $\Delta t^2$ ($<C\Delta t^2$ for some $C>0$, is it right?), but I could not understand the calculation very well.
Can somebody explain this?

Comment: The second integral doesn't really make sense to me. You are integrating with respect to $x$, with integral bounds in $t$, then evaluating _something_ from $x_{2}$ to $x_{1}$?

Comment: Sorry, sorry, it was $dt$. Many thanks.

Comment: Is the first integral correct then?

Comment: Yes, $dx$ at first.

Comment: Your google books link does not include page 40, so it is incumbent on you to explain what "$u_r$" and "$u_l$" are. Also $O(\Delta t^2)$ is a function of $\Delta t^2$, not of $t^2$, but other than that, you are correct about it.

Comment: I am sorry, I was using the impress version. I explained a little better. Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the shock speed is not constant here, which explains the $\approx$ symbols and the nonlinear shock path in Fig. 3.12. In the book, it is written that

> Assuming that $u$ is smoothly varying on each side of the shock, and that the shock speed $s(t)$ is consequently also smoothly varying, we have the following relation between $\Delta x$ and $\Delta t$:
>   $$ \Delta x = s(t_1) \Delta t + O(\Delta t^2) . \tag{3.37} $$

which is nothing else but a Taylor series of the shock path $x_s(t)$ at $t=t_1$:
$$
x_s(t_1 + \Delta t) = x_s(t_1) + s(t_1) \Delta t + O(\Delta t^2) ,
$$
where $s(t_1) = x'_s(t_1)$ is the speed of shock and $\Delta x = x_s(t_1 + \Delta t) - x_s(t_1)$. If $u$ is smoothly varying on each side of the shock, we deduce from Taylor series that
$$
u(x,t)^n = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&{u_l}^n + O(\Delta t) & &\text{if}\quad x<x_s(t)\\
&{u_r}^n + O(\Delta t) & &\text{if}\quad x>x_s(t)
\end{aligned} \right. 
$$
for all $n$ (see also textbook after Eq. $(3.38)$). Note that one can replace $O(\Delta t)$ by $O(\Delta x)$ in the previous equation, according to $(3.37)$.
Integrating $(u^2)_t + (\frac23 u^3)_x$ over the region of integration $\mathcal{D} = [x_1, x_2]\times [t_1, t_2]$ with $x_2 = x_1+\Delta x$ and $t_2 = t_1+\Delta t$, we have on the one hand
\begin{aligned}
\iint_{\mathcal D} (u^2)_t \,\text dt\text dx &= \int_{x_1}^{x_2} u^2\,\text dx \bigg|_{t_1}^{t_2} \\
&= \Delta x \left({u_l}^2 - {u_r}^2\right) + O(\Delta t \Delta x)  \\
&= s_1 \Delta t \left({u_l}^2 - {u_r}^2\right) + O(\Delta t^2) .
\end{aligned}
On the other hand,
\begin{aligned}
\iint_{\mathcal D} (\tfrac23 u^3)_x \,\text dx\text dt &= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \tfrac23 u^3\,\text dt \bigg|_{x_1}^{x_2} \\
&= \tfrac{2}{3} \Delta t \left({u_r}^3 - {u_l}^3\right) + O(\Delta t^2) ,
\end{aligned}
which yields the result.

---

Here, we have used the fact that if $f(t) = O(\Delta t)$ is a continuous function of $t$ over $[t_1, t_1+\Delta t]$, then according to the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of $O(\Delta t)$, there exists $M > 0$ and $C\geq 0$ such that
$|f(t)| \leq C \Delta t$ for all $\Delta t < M$ and all $t$ in $[t_1, t_1+\Delta t]$. The integral $I = \int_{t_1}^{t_1+\Delta t} f(t)\, \text d t$ satisfies
$$
\left|I\right| \leq \int_{t_1}^{t_1+\Delta t} \left| f(t)\right|  \text d t \leq  C \Delta t \int_{t_1}^{t_1+\Delta t} \text d t ,
$$
and thus, $I = O(\Delta t^{2})$ (see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/116668/418542)).

Comment: I'm sorry because I am still confused, could you explain one more time, please? I already accepted and bountied you, thanks. Well, at part $\iint_{\mathcal D} (u^2)_t \,\text dt\text dx = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} (u^2)\,\text dx \bigg|_{t_1}^{t_2}$ did you mean $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} (u^2)\,\bigg|_{t_1}^{t_2}\,\text dx \approx \int_{x_1}^{x_2} (u_l^2-u_r^2)\text dx =\Delta x (u_l^2-u_r^2)$, is it? Why the $\approx$ is $O(\Delta t \Delta x)$? And once the shock is on the vertexs of the rectangle, why is not $(u_r^2-u_l^2)$ for instance, I mean, why take $u_l$ in on vertex and $u_r$ at other...? Many Thanks.

Comment: @Na'omi Consider the boundary $t=t_2$. The integral reads $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} u^2\,\text dx = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} {u_l}^2 + O(\Delta t)\,\text dx .$$ Then, we are left with ${u_l}^2\times \Delta x + O(\Delta t\Delta x)$, and similarly with the other boundaries.

Comment: I think now I am understanding a little more, many thanks.